# Click in a pop-up window using python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I have 2 windows.
The first window I get is this way:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile(os.path.join(PROFILES_PATH,PROFILE_NAME))
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=EXECUTABLE_PATH)
browser.get(LIST)
```

I get data when I click on it, window 2 appears. How do I manage it from selenium?

[image]

Comment: _...I get data when I click on it, window 2 appears..._ click on which element?

Comment: I think he wants to use driver.window_handles and driver.switch_to.window to switch to another handle.